# Does Wikipedia have a project to map translated entry per language?

Tags: wikipedia, translation

Sometimes when viewing a Wikipedia entry I am interested on seeing the related entry for the counter part for an English entry to the counter part entry in other language.

One use example is: an entry for **television** in English and I want to look on the counter part entry for **television** in the German Wikipedia. Note that I admit that most entries between language are copied verbatim and translated only to the other language. But there are some entries that are unique for a culture.

Example: an entry about **tea** on the English Wikipedia may discuss worldwide tea topics (British tea, Indian, Asian) while the tea entry for chines or Japanese Wikipedia would focus on local use of tea, importance in ceremony and culture.

If you're bilingual, you can search the Tea entry for Japanese but if you're not, you cannot look for it.

I just want to know if wikipedia.org has any project for doing this or other open source project related to this. Note that this is not about translating a page (this can be done using any translation tool like Google Translate) but relating entries per wikipedia.org language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia:Translate us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Translate_us) is perhaps the project you're looking for from the encyclopaedia. But really it's more of a "heads up" and "where to start" for people who want to contribute a translation for another language or back into English.

> This page is a guide for anyone, but particularly new volunteers, willing to help translate articles from the English Wikipedia into other languages.

In particular it lists steps that you'll go through to translate. Some of which include:

> 1. Find a suitable article, which exists on the English Wikipedia, but not on the Wikipedia in the other language (or where the other language only has a stub). This tool can help.
> 2. Translate the English article into the new language.
> 3. On the other Wikipedia, go to the corresponding page, and click the button marked "create" or "edit" in the new language.
> 4. Paste your translation in. Don't worry too much about formatting at this stage.
>
> etc.

So Wikipedia has more of a guideline than an appointed committee on these efforts.

Comment: i think this only aids to translate it. but what i am looking for is for something that links articles accross languages. for example when i go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea i would like to see links to other language on same topic on diff language like for example http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8C%B6. i know people could just add link on bottom of each entry but i think it is not the practice. why?

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic on Wikipedia. Everything is done by individuals on every page in any language. There is no official project regarding any efforts to translate the English Wikipedia to other languages. Every country is kind of "responsible" to expand their articles. Wikipedia is responsible for keeping the lights on for the service. Everything else is up to the users. If you spot an error or something is missing, don't forget that you are only few steps away from actually contributing to the article.

You can click on [View History](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tea&action=history) to check all the changes since the [creation of the article](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tea&offset=2002006060606&limit=42&action=history). And the reason that you can see a direct link to the same article in other languages, is because people were kind enough to write the special markup for it in the end:

```
[[nv:Chʼil ahwééh]]
[[et:Tee (jook)]]
[[el:Τσάι]]
[[es:Té]]
[[eo:Teo]]
[[eu:Te (infusioa)]]
```

Comment: i guess your right. there is no project to do it. and just up to people to add to each entry.

Answer (score -1):

I just checked wikipedia today and when you click on the language on the left side it goes to the counter part article for the language you selected.