# Can I request a translation for a wikipedia page into a non-english language?

Tags: wikipedia

Let's say I find a rather useful page that exists in English and other languages but not in mine (French). If I don't want or can't do the translation myself, is there any way I can request a translation so someone else can see this specific page could be translated?

I found a page on [how to request a translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Translation#Requesting_a_translation_from_a_foreign_language_to_English), but specifically from another language to English.

*The page mentioned [templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Expand_by_language_Wikipedia_templates), but I couldn't find those in French.*

I also found a [page in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:Traduction/Traduire_des_articles_du_Wikip%C3%A9dia_anglais) explaining how to translate pages by yourself, but it doesn't seem to say anything about just requesting it.

Is there anything I can do to say some people would be interested in a translation of a specific page?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can ask for it. The right place is always on the subdomain of the given language mutation you want to translate it into because that's where those who know that language are usually found. There are several ways to make this request:

1. Ask someone at the embassy
2. Apply on the community page
3. Ask someone who can speak English

1. Ask someone at the embassy
   There is a page called [Wikipedia:Embassy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Embassy) available in 154 language mutations as of March 2023. So the procedure is that you click on the above link and in the list of languages (which is either on the left, in the Languages section, or it can be on the top right under the languages link. You select the language you want to translate into. You will be taken to a non-English Wikipedia page, where you have information written in English and a link to someone who can speak English. There you leave your request.
2. Apply on the community page
   Another option is to request on the community page called [Wikipedia:Village pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Village_pump) community page. It even has 250 different language mutations. You select the language in a similar way as above, with the difference that you do not have instructions in English on the community page in the selected language. Here I recommend that you be logged in under your username and when you come to the given mutation, switch to English immediately so that you can understand at least partially.
3. Ask someone who can speak English
   In this case, you start from the English page [Category:User en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:User_en) and basically click on the personal pages of users of individual language mutations who stated that they have some knowledge of English. You can post a request on their discussion page.

In conclusion, I would probably state that the request may not be granted, because the editors edit voluntarily in their free time and no one forces them to do anything. In practice, not much is translated, but rather an article is created from scratch in each language. If you do not need a specific translation, you can request an article on the [request page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Requested_articles) and proceed in a similar way as above.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't a general translation service for translating Wikipedia English articles to other languages, so you have to look at the community area of the desired target language to see if they have instructions to request a translation.

---

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Translation#Translation_from_English_to_another_language

> **Translation from English to another language**
>   Translations of an article on English Wikipedia into some other language are covered at [Wikipedia:Translate us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Translate_us).

The above link points to a help article for people willing to translate.

The same source later says

> **Other languages**
>   For translations between two non-English languages, see the versions of this page in one or other of those languages – each Wikipedia has its own standards and conventions for such translations.

Related

- [Does Wikipedia have a project to map translated entry per language?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24532/88163)
- [How can I add an article for a new language in Wikipedia?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24725/88163)

Answer (score 0):

Each local Wikipedia has its own way of handling requests.

On the English Wikipedia, the process for requesting a translation into English is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:TRANSLATETOHERE).

The current process on the French Wikipedia [appears to be](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Traduction_demand%C3%A9e) creating a stub (short) article and then adding the [`{{Suivi de traduction}}`](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod%C3%A8le:Suivi_de_traduction) template to specify the page as requesting a translation. This said, this does not to be an effective method of having someone actually translate the page on demand, based on the backlog.